# MOOCs for Python in Data Science

Tags: python, reference-request

Thanks also to SE, I've recently changed job and now I'm working in Data Science, mainly on Analytics for the IoT (Internet of Things). Analytics are applications on cloud platforms which collect real-time, streaming sensor data from industrial machines and allow to estimate their actual performance, predict the probability of a failure and the time before it happens, detect anomalies, etc..

Until now, I've been using R to build Statistical Learning models on datasets which would fit in the memory of my workstation, so I'm not a novice for what it concerns Statistical modeling and Data Science. However, I'm a novice with Python, and I need to learn it, expecially the part of the Python ecosystem related to Data Science, because that's what my team uses.

I **don't need** to develop the cloud platform: I just need to develop the "core" Analytics. I got the book by Jake Van der Plas:

[https://www.amazon.com/Python-Data-Science-Handbook-Essential/dp/1491912057](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1491912057)

but I would like to also follow a MOOC on using Python for Data Science. Can you suggest me one?

**DISCLAIMER** I already asked this question on CV and it wasn't considered very appropriate there. Since here my other question on MOOCs

[MOOC or book on Deep Learning in Python for someone with a basic knowledge of neural networks](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/20113/mooc-or-book-on-deep-learning-in-python-for-someone-with-a-basic-knowledge-of-ne)

was well-received on this site, I thought of asking again here, **after** deleting the one on CV (no cross-posting). Hope this is fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out [Applied Data Science with Python Specialization](https://www.coursera.org/specializations/data-science-python) from Coursera. It is a series of 5 courses from the University of Michigan.